# Unaware of why I am getting a 500 status express/jQuery post

Tags: jquery, forms, express, post

I'm just trying to use jQuery to do some basic front-end validation on a form, then $.post it to the backend, which will save it to my db.

This is my front end code -

```
    $('#addContact').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var contact = {};
      contact.firstName = $('#first_name').val().trim();
      contact.lastName = $('#last_name').val().trim();
      contact.company = $('#company').val().trim();
      contact.birthday = $('#birthday').val().trim();
      contact.twitterHandle = $('#twitter').val().trim();
      contact.interests = interests;
      console.log('posting', contact);

      $.post( "/addContact", contact)
        .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
      });
    });
```

And on my backend

```
    router.post('/addContact', function(req, res) {
      console.log('running post contact');
      var newContact = new Contact(temp);
      newContact.save(function(err, doc) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Added contact!');
            console.log(doc);
        }
     });
     res.end('It Worked');
    });
```

And I keep getting a 500 error.  I've checked the front end, the contact object perfectly matches the db model.  One thing I did notice in my terminal though is that the console log "running post contact" appears before the logger says "POST /addContact" so I'm not sure if that is indicating something weird is going on.  I'm currently clueless as to why this is happening though.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using mongoose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `req.body` object in order to retrieve the submitted data and then you can use this data to create a new mongoose instance

This line:

```
 var newContact = new Contact(temp);
```

Change it to:

```
 var newContact = new Contact(req.body);
```

Comment: You are correct, very dumb error on my part.  Thank you!  This was driving me up the wall,